# How can I draw a line less than 1 pixel wide

Tags: opengl, processing

Reading on this in the context of opengl I found 2 solutions:

1. If line is thiner than 1 pixel, draw 1-pixel line but use alpha blending to make it partially visible.
   +nicer results
   -problems with z-buffering (you'll have to sort lines)
2. Draw a GL_QUAD instead of line - you'll have to compute 4 vertex coordinates yourself - in application or using vertex shader.
   +thin line properly drawn using subpixel accuracy
   -line can appear 'dashed' because of fragments fitting 'between' two pixels on the screen and thus not being drawn."

https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/146742-Line-width-less-than-1-pixel

How would I do this in processing?

Comment: Do you have a legitimate use for this? Sub-pixel geometry is a performance bottleneck that we usually try to avoid rather than support :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZQ1zjPqJBPQ I'm trying to achieve this effect. When the circles get really small they certainly start to overlap, there I want instead of 1 big circle still have the illusion that it's actually a lot of small circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the `strokeWeight()` function and pass in a value less than `1`:

```
strokeWeight(.5);
line(0, 0, width, height);
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/strokeWeight_.html).

Or if you want to align more closely with the OpenGL approaches...

> If line is thiner than 1 pixel, draw 1-pixel line but use alpha blending to make it partially visible.

Just set the `stroke()` to a value that contains an alpha. Something like this:

```
stroke(0, 128);
line(0, 0, width, height);
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/stroke_.html).

> Draw a GL_QUAD instead of line - you'll have to compute 4 vertex coordinates yourself - in application or using vertex shader. +thin line properly drawn using subpixel accuracy -line can appear 'dashed' because of fragments fitting 'between' two pixels on the screen and thus not being drawn."

You can use the `beginShape()` function and pass in a parameter of `QUADS` to draw a quad. Something like this:

```
beginShape(QUADS);
vertex(0, 0);
vertex(0, 0);
vertex(width, height);
vertex(width, height);
endShape();
```

Again, more info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/beginShape_.html).

You could then use the various shader functions to use a shader. You guessed it: more info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/)

It's hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions other than by pointing you to Google and [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/). The reference should be your first stop. Read through it and look for functions that set the alpha value, or draw a quad, or use a shader. Stack Overflow is more designed for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions, so the best thing you can do is just **try something** and post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck. Good luck.